# Need help building Multiple range sliders on the same page that will display different images depending on the value of the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a web page I would like to have multiple range sliders on the same page that will display different images depending on the value of the slider . I can it do one slider but the second or third sliders dont work and also dont display the value of the slider.The images use the number of the slider value eg [0.jpg], [1,jpg], [2,jpg]

I must be doing something wrong

```
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  background: #458525
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('./images/Golf-Ball1.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
   background: url('./images/Golf-Ball1.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slidecontainer">
   <img src="./images/0.jpg" alt="" id="img">
   <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider" id="myRange1">
   <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>

   <img src="./images/0.jpg" alt="" id="img">
   <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" class="slider" id="myRange2">
   <p>Value: <span id="value"></span>
   <?php echo "aaa"; ?><br/>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;

  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "./images/" + this.value + ".jpg");
}

</script>

Any advice will be valuable to a newbe
```

Comment: Technically, HTML IDs should exist only once as it must be unique.

Comment: I am still new at this so please bear with me. I changed the ids from MyRange to MyRange1 and MyRange2, but clearly I need change the java script as well. Can you advise on how to do that